# Php sorting multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How to sort the following array?

I have an multidimensional array that gets filled with total hours for each brand

```
$totalHours = array(
                'brand'   => array(),
                'project' => array(),
                'hours'   => array()
            );
```

The output is something like this (project is not filled):

```
array(3) {
  ["brand"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Nike"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Coke Cola"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "Converse"
  }
  ["project"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Bonobo"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "LDRU"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "US"
  }
  ["hours"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(28)
    [1]=>
    int(106)
    [2]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Now I would like to sort the array based on the "hours" field.

I've tried the array_multisort but it seems like I simply don't get how this function works and how to apply it to this array. 
I have been able to sort an single array with just one row of values. If I apply that to this problem im sorting only the hours field, leaving the others unsorted and therefore the array is corrupted.

The "project" does actually contains a string. It always does. In this example I didn't filled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data format is not very convenient because there is no direct association between brands and hours, they even sit in different arrays! Plus, the last hour is a string, not an integer.

We're going to have to create an intermediate array to associate them and sort them. We'll then re-inject everything in the original array.

```
// Make sure both arrays of brands and hours and the same size
if (count($totalHours['brand']) != count($totalHours['hours'])) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid data!');
}

// Make sure every hour record is an integer, not a string
$totalHours['hours'] = array_map('intval', $totalHours['hours']);

// array_combine will sort all arrays based on the sorting of the first one
array_multisort($totalHours['hours'], $totalHours['brand'], $totalHours['project']);
```

**EDIT:** Using `array_multisort` was @delprks 's idea originally. Here I applied it to both *brand* and *project* arrays.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you help me on how to apply this including the 'project' array? or perhaps how i had to assign the values in the array the first place

Comment: My solution is not the best as I didn't use `array_multisort`. Now I read other answers, I think @delprks 's might be better for that case. I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: I've edited my answer to use `array_multisort` on *brand* and *project* arrays.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

array_multisort should work:

```
$totalHours = array(
  'brand' => array('Nike', 'Coke Cola', 'Converse'),
  'project' => array(),
  'hours' => array(28, 106, '2')
);

array_multisort($totalHours['hours'], $totalHours['brand']);

var_dump($totalHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that with a single **array_*** function!

if  **(project is not filled)** always and the indexes of **brand** and **hours** are equal, then you can do:

```
$forsort = array_combine($totalHours["brands"],$totalHours["hours"]);
asort($forsort,SORT_NUMERIC);
$totalHours["brands"]=array_keys($forsort);
$totalHours["hours"]=array_values($forsort);
```

But, this is just an answer for you question, not best practise at all.

Comment: can i just add another  $totalHours["projects"]=array_values($forsort); to add the project field?